# CSS transitionend not firing after 3 successful times

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a basic React app setup to demo this problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-forest-7ff6b

If you click on "next" giving it around 1-2 seconds between clicks, it will transition from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 happens without a transition, and then the whole thing breaks, because I listen for `transitionend` to enable a new transition.

I couldn't replicate this problem on Safari, but Chrome `79.0.3945.120` it fails every time.

I tried both `onTransitionEnd` from React as well as attaching my own event listeners. Same result.

Couldn't find any leads during my searches.

Comment: Im not sure useEffect guarantees DOM mount. It's kinda risky to use trasition like this. Try @keyframes it's easier

Comment: I would redo this example with react-spring. It would be more stable. Can change direction. And you could push the button anytime. Do you interested in it?

Comment: If you just do it as a normal counter with some animation library like that handles unmounted and mounted elements transitions which is kinda complicated  like `react-transition-group` or `react-spring` it would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I still don't understand what's the underlying problem here? And why does Chrome act differently from Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reliably work with `onTransitionEnd` or a more direct `transitionend` event listener, but I was able to achieve the same results using CSS animation listeners.

```
<div onAnimationEnd={onNavigationEnd} />
```